# What can we do with a problem?

Tags: verbs, collocation

We could solve a problem, obviously.
Is it possible to use "break", "beat", "hit", "crack" with the meaning of "solve"? I'm trying to find some more emotional equivalent.

Comment: Go search the corpora and rank the words fitting in that slot.

Comment: One could also _climax_ with a problem, given a certain emotional involvement

Comment: I _avoid_ problems.

Comment: Have you checked? http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/solve http://thesaurus.com/browse/solve  http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/solve/ http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/solve

Comment: If the _problem_ is a woman, you should definitely not _beat_, _hit_ or _crack_ it! :)

Comment: Please do not ask open ended question where all answers are equally valid. If possible, please can you [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/108100/edit) your question, so that it is asking for something that isn't just a list of words.

Comment: @RaduMiron- Your second comment sheds some light on your first suggestion.

Comment: @Jim That's strange, since no connection was intended. Why would you need a certain emotional involvement to climax with a woman? It makes no sense. :P (settle down, people, it's just a joke :D)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [***overcome***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overcome) : 2. To prevail over; surmount

Example usages from [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/overcome):

> “In fact, the very first hurdle most writers have to overcome, is to shout down the voice in their own head that tells them that their writing is worthless.”
>   [The Harshest Critic « Write Anything](http://writeanything.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/the-harshest-critic/)
>
> “Of course one problem we're going to have to overcome is that while a psychiatrist may excel in what they do in the real world, they're probably not going to be very good at playing World of Warcraft.”
>   [Boing Boing](http://www.boingboing.net/2009/07/26-week/)

Answer (score 0):

We could **clear up** a problem. Although, are you looking for just one word?